# How to use Javascript to extract and parse four parts of a complex date field for use in other fields

Tags: javascript

Thanks to some help here, I've been able to get further.

I'm trying to extract the four parts of a user-entered date field and use them to create 4 distinct values in the same object in a Knack.com database.

The user enters a complex date that has Start Date, Start Time, End Date, End Time. In my object, I have fields for each of those four values.

I want to set those fields to the extracted values, based on a suggestion here, I've gotten it parsed, but am getting unexpected values in the JSON. ?

```js
$(document).on('knack-record-create.view_222', function(event, view, record) {
     
  // use data from inserted record
     
 
console.log(record);
 
    var enteredDate = $("#view_222-field_302_raw").val();
     
    var getData = JSON.parse( enteredDate );
 
alert(getData.date); //output: 02/08/2013
alert(getData.hours); //output: 2
alert(getData.minutes); //output: 0
alert(getData.am_pm); //output: pm
 
for(i=0;i<getData.to.length;i++)
{
    alert(getData["to"][i].date); //output: 02/11/2013
    alert(getData["to"][i].hours); //output: 2
    alert(getData["to"][i].minutes); //output: 0
    alert(getData["to"][i].am_pm); //output: pm
}
data.field_74 = { 
      date: Data.date // start date
     
  }
   
data.field_200 =  { // start time
      hours: Data.hours, // start hours
      minutes: Data.minutes, // start minutes
      am_pm: Data.am_pm, // start hours
                 
  }
   
data.field_201 = { // end date
      date: Data[to][i].date // start date
                 
  }
  
data.field_134 = { // end time
      hours: Data[to][i].hours, // start hours
      minutes: Data[to][i].minutes, // start minutes
      am_pm: Data[to][i].am_pm, // start am_pm
                 
  }
     
  // update the record
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_8/records/" + record.id,
    type: "PUT",
    headers: {"X-Knack-Application-Id": "xxx", "X-Knack-REST-API-Key":"xxx"},
    data: data,
    success: function(response) { 
         
      console.log('Record updated!');
    }   
  });
     
});
```

Comment: looks like you are setting your `startd`, `startt`, `endd`, and `endt` to the html elements described by the ids: `view_259-field_299` and `view_259-field_299-time`. This might be what you want, but I think you will want to get the actually data from the element. Depending on what type of tag they are this it is a little different. Also `data` _might_ be initialized incorrectly (looks like you are missing a "," between `endt`  and `data`.

Comment: post the format of the string the user enters, otherwise its hard to help with parsing the date string

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
  "date":"02/08/2013",
  "hours":2,
  "minutes":0,
  "am_pm":"pm"
  "to":{
    "date":"02/11/2013"
    "hours":2,
    "minutes":0,
    "am_pm":"pm"
  },
}
```

You can parse the above code like

```
var getData = JSON.parse(data);

alert(getData.date); //output: 02/08/2013
alert(getData.hours); //output: 2
alert(getData.minutes); //output: 0
alert(getData.am_pm); //output: pm

for(i=0;i<getData.to.length;i++)
{
    alert(getData["to"][i].date); //output: 02/11/2013
    alert(getData["to"][i].hours); //output: 2
    alert(getData["to"][i].minutes); //output: 0
    alert(getData["to"][i].am_pm); //output: pm
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried updating my code with the parse inserted.

Comment: You're correct, Noah. I wanted to get the information from the html element.